# How can I move the placeholder Label from UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have created a simple extended `UISearchBar` which is a bit smaller then the native one. I have implemented this code :

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

   CGRect frame = self.frame;
    if (frame.size.height != 32) {
        frame.size.height = 32;
        self.frame = frame;
    }

    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#636363"]}];
    UITextField *searchTextField = [self valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    UILabel *placeholderLabel = [searchTextField valueForKey:@"_placeholderLabel"];

    placeholderLabel.frame = CGRectMake(placeholderLabel.frame.origin.x , placeholderLabel.frame.origin.y + 8 , placeholderLabel.frame.size.width , placeholderLabel.frame.size.height);
    [placeholderLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [placeholderLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];

    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#c6c6c6"]];

    self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#949494"] CGColor];

    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:5];


}
```

but the result is like this :

[image]

The placeholder label is still not in the center of the view. And I can not figure out how can I move it there. The font can be changed the background color as well, but the label remains stuck in the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer was to add to UISearchBar a height constraint and set it to 32. The magic is done, and the placeholder is positioned well.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement your own control, because you will be unable to move the search placeholder around.

Comment: I have implemented my own uisearchbar And I have modified it. The question is why I can not modify the placeholder fram

Comment: Because that is native control, and on the position of the label can not be modified. Even narrowing the control by itself is not recommended at all.
 
If you want a narrower UISearchBar, with a label positioned in the middle, than you should create a UITextField, and a placeholder label in the middle.